# Looking for a cheap laser mono printer (for home usage) that works perfectly?

Tags: printing, hardware

By "perfectly" I mean:

1. No proprietary driver install (works out of the box)
2. Full featured driver: duplex printing (if supported by the printer), adjustable printing quality, printer maintenance routines, etc...

And it has to be **cheap**, because I'll use it just to occasionally print a bunch of text documents, at low quality, and printing on both sides.

Comment: What price range would consider as "cheap"? (It varies from country to country, and from person to person.)

Comment: Less than 150 EUR. Sorry for being not precise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally bought an HP LaserJet P1102 for two reasons:

1. It seems HP supports Linux outstandingly, and I can confirm it does
2. The printer is damn cheap: got it for 69€.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a Samsung ML-2851ND. It works under many - perhaps all - Linux Distributions out of the box without the need to install any additional software. It's a small printer for the SOHO market, so that the toner is quite expensive (compared to big office printers), but compared to similar printers from HP or Brother, it's quite cheap.

The printer has Ethernet, so that you can print from any computer inside your LAN. It has a Duplexer, so that you can print on both sides of a page. And it is a compact printer, so that it doesn't clutter your room.

I'm using the printer with Ubuntu 10.10, 11.04 and 11.10 without problems. It is automatically detected by the printing utility. If you like to read more, you might [visit my blog](http://linuxundich.de/de/hardware/kompakter-mono-laser-samsung-ml-2851nd-unter-ubuntu-linux/), unfortunately it's written in German, perhaps the [Google Translater](http://translate.google.de/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://linuxundich.de/de/hardware/kompakter-mono-laser-samsung-ml-2851nd-unter-ubuntu-linux/) is goo enough for you.

Christoph

Comment: Thanks for your kind and useful help. By the way, do you know if the openprinting.org website is down forever or will be up again soon or later?

Answer (score 1):

I can also confirm that HP printers perform outstandingly in Ubuntu. I have HP LaserJet 1018 and it works fantastic! It was relatively cheap, works right out of the box, prints perfectly ... I couldn't be happier. I also use it to print from VirtualBox and that also works without any problems.

I think any HP printer which is at least a year old model should work right out of the box in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Oki 431 gets very good reviews for the price point...and I just got one today.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to get it set up properly in Ubuntu 12.04 PP, which is why I'm surfing the "printing" tags this evening...if I get it to work I'll try to remember to report back with an update.